# Adding Ground Overlays to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I use an example from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple)
When I add my own photograph, then this works well.

But when I change the coordinates, then the photograph don't display anymore.

I get the coordinates from adding a image (image overlay) in Google Earth.

I'm don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ground Overlays</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
  }
</style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
// This example uses a GroundOverlay to place an image on the map
// showing an antique map of Newark, NJ.

var historicalOverlay;

function initialize() {

  var newark = new google.maps.LatLng(58.8110, 8.526);
  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(58.989835, 9.050201),
      new google.maps.LatLng(58.612911, 7.917444));

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: newark
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'http://xxxxxxxxx/test/images/map/kart.JPG',
      imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can we say what you are doing wrong when you didn't show what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

the expected arguments for `LatLngBounds` are

1. SouthWest
2. NorthEast

...but you've provided:

1. NorthEast
2. SouthWest

switch the arguments and you'll see the image

```js
// This example uses a GroundOverlay to place an image on the map
// showing an antique map of Newark, NJ.

var historicalOverlay;

function initialize() {

  var newark = new google.maps.LatLng(58.8110, 8.526);
  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(58.612911, 7.917444),
      new google.maps.LatLng(58.989835, 9.050201)
  );

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: newark
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
map.fitBounds(imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA4e2.jpg?s=256&g=1',
      imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```